# Can anyone suggest how to handle the error which i was facing when using to call an Post and get Http methods through protractor?

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, automation, protractor

I am Trying to execute a GET API request from protractor for which I have to Use the bearer token generated from another POST response . I am able to run the POST request successfully ,but unable to use the generated token in GET request in headers . Below is the code-snippet which I tried , Can anyone provide the proper syntax on this approach .

Note : URL and credentials are masked as they are confidential

var Request =  require("request");

describe('post user request', () => {

```
it('create user test', (done) => {
              
        //1. create user (POST)
        Request.post({
          //  method: 'POST',
            "url": "http://example.com",
            
            "body" : {
                "username": "abc",
                "password": "abc1",
            }
```

}).then((res)=>{
console.log(JSON.stringify(res))

```
        }).then((res) =>{
               const token1 = res.token 
                //2. get user (GET)
                Request.get({
               //  method: 'GET',
                  "url": "http://example.com`[enter code here][1]`/xyz",
                 "headers": {
                        "Authorization" : "Bearer " + token1
                    }
                }).then((res)=>{
                    console.log(res)
                    done();
                   
                })
        })
```

})
})

```
Error message : 
F
  post user request
    × create user test
      - Failed: Argument error, options.body.


Failures:
1) post user request create user test
  Message:
    Failed: Argument error, options.body.
  Stack:
    Error: Argument error, options.body.
        at setContentLength (D:\Protractor\node_modules\request\request.js:437:28)
        at Request.init (D:\Protractor\node_modules\request\request.js:442:5)
        at new Request (D:\Protractor\node_modules\request\request.js:127:8)
        at request (D:\Protractor\node_modules\request\index.js:53:10)
        at Function.post (D:\Protractor\node_modules\request\index.js:61:12)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (D:\Protractor\Specs_Map\APIfile.spec.js:8:21)
        at D:\Protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.j
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Comment: `tokenvalue` is only available in the "POST" test. Ask the API for a method that gets you the token (there will be something to "log into" that API) and use that in your test.

Comment: Please read the description of a tag before you use it. The `[api]` tag shouldn't be used -> _"DO NOT USE. Use specific tags like `[google-cloud-platform]`, `[facebook]`, `[amazon-web-services]` instead or `[api-design]` where applicable."_

Comment: You should just login to the website with this information in an automated way with Protractor by filling in the user name and password OR create some API functional tests without Protractor.

Comment: I require the working code for the above scenario using Protractor

Answer (score 0):

`}).then((res)=>{ console.log(JSON.stringify(res))` this is where your error comes from.

Here you log the result, but don't return it, so the following `then` won't get any value.

Try the following:
    `}).then((res)=>{ console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); return res;`